# SharePoint 2013 immediate alerts keeps on sending duplicate emails

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-alerts

We have share point 2013 environment and If we set the immediate alerts on any library or lists it keeps on sending the notification frequently with 5-10 min gap with the same change details as updated by the user.

Basically It keeps on sending duplicate notification mails until we disable the alert on the library.

Kindly guide and suggest me what could be the reason for the same.

Thanks,
Kailash

Answer (score 0):

If immediate alerts keeps on sending duplicate emails, you can confirm this through the GUI:

Navigate to list-> Click Alert Me, and then click Manage My Alerts->delete the duplicate alert on the list.

You can also delete all SharePoint alerts from a list using PowerShell,  Then readd alert on the list.

Refer to the following article about how to delete all SharePoint alerts from a list using PowerShell:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/11/managing-alerts-using-powershell.html

Comment: I have already checked there is no duplicate alerts subscribed for the library. The library has only one alert subscribed. The issue is appearing for any library even if I try to create one new library and set an alert.

Comment: Hello,
I checked as per your suggestion, but still the issue persists.
Now I noticed the issue only appears for one specific site collection.
I got some ULS log for the immediateAlerts timer job issue and mentions as below.


The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPImmediateAlertsJobDefinition (ID 8f820716-64f2-4ab0-adbe-afd2927c05bd) threw an exception. More information is included below.
Cannot complete this action.

I did the SP configuration cache cleaning, restarted the timer service in all the servers, but no luck

Kindly help.